# Win 10 does not run scheduled optimisation task

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, scheduled-tasks, trim

I have win 10 with all latest updates (14393.321)

In my drives tab I set SSD optimization to run daily. But this task does not run in 9 days.

[image]

Comment: BTW you don't need to defragment your SSD at all!

Comment: It doesn't actually defragment (from what I know) but rather run TRIM. It could be that it's either not needed or that it's waiting for some idle time on the system to actually do it. Is the system in constant use?

Comment: this is a Trim optimisation, not a defragment. @Seth no, system is not in constant use.